# Shorten the Table Names in Oracle

Tags: oracle, vba, oracle11g, url-shortener

I have a requirement where i read table_name from user_tables and append 6 letters after the table_name at run time for e.g.

```
prev_table_name= F_ALIGN_PROF_PRD_MTH_SLS_NM2
New_table_name = prev_table_name_ABCDE
```

so new table name is exceeding the limit of 30 characters and i am getting an error.

to overcome this problem i am looking for a method so i can shorten the table_name at run time and append my 6 letters to it.

Kindly suggest any workaround fo this problem

Comment: Sounds like you would need to substr() the previous table name to 24 characters then.

Comment: i can do that but the table_name will be F_ALIGN_PROF_PRD_MTH_S, which will create confusion while reading

Comment: You can remove to last '_' like this F_ALIGN_PROF_PRD_MTH

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this, then?

```
select substr(substr('F_ALIGN_PROF_PRD_MTH_SLS_NM2', 1, 24),
              1,
              instr(substr('F_ALIGN_PROF_PRD_MTH_SLS_NM2', 1, 24), '_', -1)) substr_table_name
from   dual;

SUBSTR_TABLE_NAME    
---------------------
F_ALIGN_PROF_PRD_MTH_
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want such result ?

```
select SUBSTR('prev_table_name_ABCDE' , 1, 6) from dual 

Result : prev_t
```

If you want readable name you can take to last '_'

```
 SELECT SUBSTR('prev_table_name_ABCDE', 1 ,INSTR('prev_table_name_ABCDE', '_',1,3)-1)
FROM dual;

Result :prev_table_name
```

Comment: no, i am looking for something that will shorten my table_name without loosing its readability

Comment: @anurag as I mentioned above do you want it like this 'prev_table_name' or tell me what is output result you desire

Comment: i want result like 
prev_name=F_ALIGN_PROF_PRD_MTH_SLS_NM2 and new_name=F_ALGN_PRF_PRD_MTH_SLS_NM_ABCD

Answer (score 0):

I found one way to do it (its an temporary solution but it will work)

Read the table name and remove all vowels and numbers from it.

Comment: What if there are no vowels or numbers to remove, or removing them leaves the tablename longer than 24 characters?

Comment: thats why its a temporary solution, as my all tables have vowels in it

Answer (score 0):

how about creating a a new table to store the old and new tablename?

```
my_table
  oldname F_ALIGN_PROF_PRD_MTH_SLS_NM2
  newname TEMP_ABCD
```